# What version of Android should I develop for?

Tags: android, version, wysiwyg

Just started to develop for Android, the idea is to create an app available on the Android Market. I would really like to be able to use the bulit in "Graphical Layout" (WYSIWYG) to create the UI. I now have two questions:

1. From what I can see almost all users are currently using Android version 2.2 or earlier. From what I understand there are lots of improvements in the 3.0 version specially when creating the UI, but when will 3.0 version be available for larger mass? Should I continue to develop for 2.X users or should I go with 3.0?
2. Do you recommend me to use the "Graphical Layout" to create the UI or should I do it manually using the xml-files? I've read that the "Graphical Layout" wasn't working that good in earlier version but is much better for 3.0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Current data looks more like:
60% on 2.2,
27% on 2.1,
1% on 2.3*,
6% on 1.6,
5% on 1.5

So with 2.1+ you reach 88% of the market. 3.0 is for sure something of the future, but only available for tablets right now - developing exclusively for it will leave all the mobiles out for a long time.

The graphical layout editors get better and better - I did not have much luck when I looked at them 9 month ago, but the situation has changed.

I'd propose to look at them and use them - and then a) have a look at the results and b) optimize the result if the graphical editor's is not what you want.

Comment: Can you please give the reference to these figures.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html

Comment: Android market application, publish section, statistics window for my app.

Comment: Thanks! Ok I guess I stick with 2.1 then, and see if I can get anything out of the Graphical Editor.

Comment: @Martin & @Heiko: Got it from @Roflcoptr's answer, thanks anyway. +1.

Answer (score 6):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html) you can find the distribution of Android platform versions. It will need some times until a large part of the users are using 3.0. So I would recommend to focus on Android 2.1 and higher if you have to specify. If you develop for 3.0 only, no one will be able to use your application. That can't really be your goal, right?

What exactly are you're referring when you mentioned "Graphical Layout"? The visual GUI editor? If that, I would recommend to do your layout in the XML file and then you could check how it looks in the "Graphical Layout".

Comment: Yes, the Visual GUI editor in Eclipse, when I open an xml file it opens up in the "Graphical Layout".

Comment: Ok i see. Then I agree with Heiko Rupp. Last time I checked it wasn't really great, maybe the have improved it a lot, so you could give it a try. Nevertheless I think it always better to do your GUI programatically and not in a GUI editor.