# Android - Which version to develop for?

Tags: android

I am asked to develop a simple android application. Am almost done with it. (Am a experienced java developer).

My question is. The app more or less is a webview. Which Android version should I build for?
Of course - you should always build for the newest version - But most of the android phones still run old software (2.1).

Should I build the app for 2.1?

Comment: Go with 2.2 http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html

Comment: [Exact Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5456717/940096)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably build for 4.0.4, but set minimum SDK version to 2.1. The minimum version should be chosen based on what is your app requiring. You can set it even to 1.5 if you don't use any newer features and you know what you're doing (you would probably need to do more testing).

Comment: Na min sdk 2.2, it brings goodies that are worth more than the amount of users you get for 2.1

Comment: with minimum sdk version of 2.1 you will cover a wide majority of the target devices, as you can see in this graph: http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html

Comment: So if i build for 4.0.4, and set min sdk to 2.1 / 2.2 the app will run on older devices, if i don't use any 4.0.4 "only" features?

How about the javascript engine, and other stuff?

Comment: @hogni89, yes, it will run. I don't know about javascript, just test it on the API levels you support.

Answer (score 1):

If you are aiming for maximum compatibility then yes, 2.1 would be the optimal choice. Approximately 1% of devices are using an API lower than this.

Take a look at the [Current Distribution](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html) Android page for a more detailed overview.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take that decision yourself. If you want to cover a wider market with your app, then 2.1 or 2.2 would be a preferred version. If your app is client specific, then go with what they want. Perhaps [this link](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html) could help you to take a proper decision if you're building a market release app.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefere Android 2.3.x or 2.2 becuase the most smartphones use one of this both versions. Another advantage is, that 2.3.x and 2.2 is compatible to the newest version of Android.

I hope it's a usefull answer.

Good luck from Germany.